# start y-axis from 0 in ng2-charts

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am using ng2-charts to generate a graph. I want the y-axis to start from 0.
I used :
  1.scaleBeginAtZero: true
  2.beginAtZero: true

Both didn't work.
In my package.json file, the versions of chartsjs and ng2-charts are as follows:
"chart.js": "^2.7.1",
"ng2-charts": "^1.6.0"

Answer (score 0):

For Enable Y-axis to start from 0

```
this.chartOptions = {
  scales: {
      yAxes: [{
         scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Y axis label'
         },
         ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
         }
      }]
  },
  maintainAspectRatio: false
}
```

By Using beignAtZero inside ticks for y-axis scale, then your chart starts from 0

Chart Js version

```
"chart.js": "2.8.0"
```

Ng2-Charts Version

```
"ng2-charts": "2.3.0",
```